# how to remove the first slash in django?

Tags: django

The tutorial is written like this

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include("polls.urls")
```

but i prefer

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('/admin', admin.site.urls),
    path('/polls', include("polls.urls")
```

So the url would be '127.0.0.1:8000//polls' 
Is there any way to remove the first slash that is automatically added?

I try to set APPEND_SLASH = FALSE but it makes nothing

Comment: Why `//polls`? What sense does that make?

Comment: I don't want //polls either, so I'm wondering if there's a way to remove the first slash added by django. I expect the result to be /polls, with the only slash being written by me.

Comment: OK, that is extremely easy to misunderstand that way you've written it. Quite frankly: Django's urlpatterns work as they do. Just because you _prefer_ to write them differently isn't really enough reason to change it. Just accept what they are, end of story. If you _really_ insist: write a small wrapper around `path` which simply removes the starting slash. That allows you to write `/polls` but have it behave like `polls`.

Comment: `def mypath(p, *args, **kwargs): return path(p.lstrip('/'), *args, **kwargs)`

Answer (score 0):

- In Django,the leading slash in the URL pattern is intentional and is
  part of the design.

  That means, even if you configure as:

  ```
  urlpatterns = [
  path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
  path('polls/', include("polls.urls")),]
  ```

  The api will would look like : https://127.0.0.1:8000/polls/
- But, if you want to remove the trailing slash from URLs, you can use
  the CommonMiddleware with the APPEND_SLASH settings.

  In your settings.py add:

  ```
  APPEND_SLASH = False
  ```

  **In middleware configuration:**

  If setting APPEND_SLASH to False is not having any effect, then there might be other middleware or configurations in your project that might be affecting this behavior. So, you might have to check the order of middleware in your MIDDLEWARE setting in settings.py.

> Ensure that CommonMiddleware is placed before other middleware that
> might interfere with URL handling.

```
   MIDDLEWARE = [
       # ...
       'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
       # ...
   ]
```

Then your api will would look like : https://127.0.0.1:8000/polls